# Where is the ufprt located

Tags: unit-testing, protractor, integration-testing, umbraco

I recently started working with unit testing, specially integration test. I am working on a afterAll function that deletes the test that was created during the process. I need the ufprt because it's giving me a 400 status code, I am using Umbraco, I am new to it as well. Here is my afterAll function.
NOTE: there is an specified ufprt there, but it's not the one I am supposed to use. I am working in Visual Studio, using Protractor with Jasmine.

```
afterAll(function () {
    const HttpClient = require("protractor-http-client").HttpClient;
    const http = new HttpClient(browser.params.server);
    var post = http.post("/login", "login=&loginModel.Password=infox2016&loginModel.Username=unittestmember1@infox.de&ufprt=A281647162F7381054DAACAE0536261EB29527977AF7313C526A081FFC2DDB2A0F62993C7FBC9759ED43AC448BAF0611667A521E6BD247C6D23535438FDC94209A9F028E01028B9F58B20205EB39701D81DA06E360441239F0FF57F287B231D4426EED4713957FBEDC2B9C31D8DD88D6B3E89B12B58B1C688BD42B7340CE7F89E7330B48F051A5BCE86C2110BDAE14061BFB02250CADF837B46D7F77D2E7DACA", {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    });
    browser.wait(post.then(function (response) {
        response = http.delete("api/CampaignConfiguration/" + browser.params.id);
        console.log(browser.params.id);
        browser.wait(response.then(function (deleteResponse) {
            expect(deleteResponse.statusCode).toBe(200);
        }));
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found where is it located. After login in the website, in the start page, i clicked F12, then went to Network, marked All. I clicked on the first option and then Headers, and there it was, in the Form Data section.